# Switch users without typing password or FaceID

Tags: macos, apple-watch, touch-id

Apple says: use Apple Watch to unlock your mac without typing password or TouchID.

I have two user accounts on my mac. Both tied to the same Apple ID and password.

I am wearing an Apple Watch 6.

When I switch between the accounts I always have to use TouchID or password.

Any way to make it switch without requiring TouchID or password, just by wearing the watch?

Comment: Curious about why you have two user accounts that use the same Apple ID. Doesn't that duplicate a lot of data (iCloud Drive, Photos, etc.) on your computer? Just wondering what your use case is.

Comment: because I work for a company that requires everything to be setup in a particular way, like monitor resolutions, account names, etc., but I need the stuff I have on iCloud to be accessible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple Watch and macOS allow you to *unlock* your Mac. When trying to switch accounts, your Mac is already unlocked. So, no, I don't think Apple Watch will help you switch accounts.

Comment: thanks. I was suspecting that.